# How to insert a column and it's values from another table without a common field in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two tables in postgresql **without** a common field.

- Table1 has a TIMESTAMP field.
- Table2 has FIRST_TIMESTAMP, LAST_TIMESTAMP and SEGMENT_ID fields.

How can i insert SEGMENT_ID field and it's values from Table2 to the Table1, based on a **condition** like;

"If Table1.TIMESTAMP is between Table2.FIRST_TIMESTAMP and Table2.LAST_TIMESTAMP"

(If Table1.TIMESTAMP>=Table2.FIRST_TIMESTAMP AND Table1.TIMESTAMP<=Table2.LAST_TIMESTAMP)

Answers could include a postgresql UPDATE statement rather than INSERT statement too.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a SEGMENT_ID column in Table1 too?

Comment: No, there is not a common field in tables.

Comment: Then what column would be updated in Table1?

Comment: I can add a SEGMENT_ID field to Table1 before the update statement. SEGMENT_ID field in Table1 will be populated according to the condition.

Comment: So after you added the segment_id field to Table1 you want to do something like [MERGE](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/55920/sql-merge.html) (aka upsert) all dates in the Table2 ranges + segment_id into Table1?

Comment: I want to MERGE (aka upsert) only SEGMENT_ID row values from table2 to the table1, based on the mentioned if condition.

Comment: Your condition is valid only if there are rows in both tables to compare the timestamps, so what you want is UPDATE.

Comment: Ok then if UPDATE works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax of the join on the condition that the timestamp of table1 must be between the 2 timestamps of table2 for postgresql:

```
update table1 t1
set segment_id = t2.segment_id
from table2 t2
where t1.timestamp between t2.first_timestamp and t2.last_timestamp
```

Comment: I got following error; "ERROR:  relation "table2" does not exist
LINE 3: from table2 t2          SQL state: 42P01"

Comment: Here is a simplified demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ab4978d913e8fa8e7c7f00d6f54c32ef As you can see it is syntactically correct.

Comment: Did you change the names of the tables with the actual names that you have?

Comment: Yes i've changed to the actual table names. Your dbfiddle link  seems like exacty what i want but i am still getting  this error.

Comment: The error says that there is no table2. Are you sure this table exists or maybe you have misspelled it?

Comment: It was a long table name. I've changed it to a short one. Now It seems working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (segment_id, col1, col2, ...)
SELECT segment_id, col1, col2, ... FROM table2 WHERE <where_condition>;
```

Note that if you are `INSERT`ing, there's no existing `table1.timestamp`, so you can't compare it with `table2`, so you'll need to come up with a different `where_condition`.

For `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET col1 = table2.segment_id
  FROM table2
 WHERE table1.timestamp_col BETWEEN table2.first_timestamp AND table2.last_timestamp;
```